# How to add response cards in Amazon Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

[image]I am trying to add a Response card to one of the prompt using GUI as described in this following documentation [Using Response Card](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-resp-card.html) 
But When i build and test the Bot I am only getting text prompts not the Response card.
So I am unable to find out where i am going wrong.
How to solve this ?

Comment: Did you specify title? Can you share the screenshot of your response card that you have defined in console?

Comment: i have added the screenshot, if anything else is required let me know @Saurabh

Comment: check out this answer for detailed steps of how to add response cards. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646930/3196845

Answer (score 4):

So, first thing to know: **Response Cards are not shown in Amazon Lex Test Console!**

I realized this after many frustrating attempts to have an image rendered in Lex’s Test Console. This can be found in the official docs [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-sch-appt-fb-integration.html)

I have made [this example](https://github.com/imTachu/ShakiraChatbot/blob/5b21537fb01e89c3167fc6b941699f0532368c2b/chatbot/botcontrol.py#L146) of a chatbot I made for Facebook Messenger and it renders Response Cards perfectly.

Comment: Do you know if Response Cards are supported in Web Embed ? https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui