# Creating carousel card in AWS Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, carousel, chatbot, facebook-chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to build a ecommerce chatbot using lex.

Is there any solution to use a carousel card or multi response cards in Lex?

For example:

[image]

Thanks..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can display multiple response cards in the response and it will display like carousel. 
Follow [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/ex-resp-card.html) to generate response card through console (you can also do it dynamically in code).

**Console method:**
In the below image, in `Prompt response cards` section, see in the rightmost part, there is little `+` button, click on that and you can add more cards.

[image]

**Dynamic method (using Lambda):**

```
'dialogAction': {
    'type': 'Close',
    'fulfillmentState': 'Fulfilled',
    'message': {
        'contentType': 'PlainText',
        'content': message
    },
    'responseCard': {
    'version': '0',
    'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
    'genericAttachments': [
        {
        'title': 'title1',
        'subTitle': 'subtitle1',
        'attachmentLinkUrl': 'link_that_will_open_on_click',
        'imageUrl': 'link_of_image_to_display',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button_1",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_2",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_3",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             }
            ]
        },
        {
        'title': 'title2',
        'subTitle': 'subtitle2',
        'attachmentLinkUrl': 'link_that_will_open_on_click',
        'imageUrl': 'link_of_image_to_display',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button_1",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_2",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_3",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             }
            ]
        },
        {
        'title': 'title3',
        'subTitle': 'subtitle3',
        'attachmentLinkUrl': 'link_that_will_open_on_click',
        'imageUrl': 'link_of_image_to_display',
        "buttons":[ 
             {
                "text":"button_1",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_2",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             },
             {
                "text":"button_3",
                "value":"value_to_be_sent_to_server_on_click"
             }
            ]
        }
    ]

    }
}
```

**NOTE 1:** You can have `maximum of 10 response cards` in the carousel, and `maximum of 3 buttons` in a single carousel.
If you have more than 10 cards, you will get error.
If you have more than 3 buttons, you won't get error but only first 3 will be shown.
**NOTE 2:** You need to check `messaging_postbacks` events in the `Webhooks` in messenger settings in the Facebook app to make buttons of carousel work.

I have implemented response cards in below manner:

[image]
See cards are coming like carousel, you can swipe to see more cards.

Hope it helps.

Comment: also, you need to check "messaging_postbacks" events in the Webhooks in messenger settings in the Facebook app to make buttons of carousel work.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful. I can do it by using console. But i couldn't find a code example or post message sample for carousel. Is there any example ? Thanks..

Comment: @Murat, I have updated the answer and added the sample code. let me know if you have any confusion. vote and mark as accepted answer if it fulfill your purpose.

Comment: This response should be marked as an accepted answer. Good job @sid8491 on providing a detailed response. You would want to put the message_postback option selection thing a part of your response instead of leaving it out in comment here

Comment: Thanks. This response message is really great example.

Comment: @Murat consider marking it as accepted answer if it helped you so that it can reach wider audience