# How to add response card

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-lex

I am trying to create a bot using `C# .NET SDK` for **AWS Lex**. I was searching online and exploring `AWS Lex API` reference on my own but still haven't found a way to add `response card` in my bot.

I have checked `PutSlotTypeRequest`, `PutIntentRequest`, and `PutBotRequest` but still couldn't find a way to include response card to my Slot. I have seen field called `responseCard` however, this field is of type `string` and not a `ResponseCard` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ResponseCard` is not part of `Slot` or `Intent`, that is why we can not add it through `PutSlotTypeRequest` or `PutIntentRequest`. It is part of the response which your bot is providing.
You can configure a response if a slot is not filled by the user and add a response card to that response.

Below code is the sample code of how to add response card:

```
"dialogAction": {
    "type": "Close",
    "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled or Failed",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText or SSML",
      "content": "Message to convey to the user. For example, Thanks, your pizza has been ordered."
    },
   "responseCard": {
      "version": integer-value,
      "contentType": "application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic",
      "genericAttachments": [
          {
             "title":"card-title",
             "subTitle":"card-sub-title",
             "imageUrl":"URL of the image to be shown",
             "attachmentLinkUrl":"URL of the attachment to be associated with the card",
             "buttons":[ 
                 {
                    "text":"button-text",
                    "value":"Value sent to server on button click"
                 }
              ]
           } 
       ] 
     }
  }
```

For more details about ResponseCard, please check [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646930/3196845)

Hope it helps.