# Hyperlink in response card button in Amazon Lex

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, facebook-chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to make a response card in amazon lex to give out a response card that has a button that leads to another website. Below is the code that I have used in aws lambda python. I have published the chatbot on facebook messenger. But whenever I select the button in fb messenger, the link in the button does not seem to bring me to the website. Is there any way to make the response card button turn into hyperlink button?

```
def location(intent_request):

    session_attributes = intent_request['sessionAttributes'] if intent_request['sessionAttributes'] is not None else {}

    return {
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'Close',
            'fulfillmentState': 'Fulfilled',
            'message': {
                'contentType': 'PlainText',
                'content': 'Here is a map'
            },
            'responseCard': {
            'version': '17',
            'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
            'genericAttachments': [
                {
                'title': 'Here is a list of hospitals',
                'subTitle': 'Below is a map',
                "buttons":[
                     {
                        "text":"Show Google Maps",
                        "value":"https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=nearby+hospitals"
                     }
                    ]
                }
            ]
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of now you cannot do that using the buttons. The buttons have two parameters `text` and `value`. **When you click on a button, the `value` of button is sent to the servers and the `text` is appended to the chat.** So it will just send the value back to `Lex` but cannot open function as hyperlink.

However you can use image in the response card for the same functionality. `imageUrl` is the url of the image to be displayed, and `attachmentLinkUrl` is the url which you want to open. So I would suggest you to remove buttons and use an image of map to be shown and provide your hyperlink in `attachmentLinkUrl`.
Also, if you want to show multiple hyperlink, you can show multiple cards (upto 10) in a single `responseCard`.

Below is a sample code:

```
return {
    'dialogAction': {
        'type': 'Close',
        'fulfillmentState': 'Fulfilled',
        'message': {
            'contentType': 'PlainText',
            'content': message
        },
        'responseCard': {
        'version': '0',
        'contentType': 'application/vnd.amazonaws.card.generic',
        'genericAttachments': [
            {
            'title': 'Here is a list of hospitals',
            'subTitle': 'Below is a map',
            'attachmentLinkUrl': 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=nearby+hospitals',
            'imageUrl': 'https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_optimized,f_auto/p/95612986-96d5-11e6-af7c-00163ec9f5fa/3771854867/google-maps-screenshot.png'
            },
            {
            'title': 'Here is a list of medical shops',
            'subTitle': 'Below is a map',
            'attachmentLinkUrl': 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=nearby+medical+shops',
            'imageUrl': 'https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_optimized,f_auto/p/95612986-96d5-11e6-af7c-00163ec9f5fa/3771854867/google-maps-screenshot.png'
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646930/3196845) as well for details about response cards.
Hope it helps.