# Response card in Amazon lex

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am using Amazon lex to build a chatbot. When I was trying to build a response card using lambda function as a validation code-hook, I observed that the maximum number of buttons in a response card must be five. 
Can we increase the number of buttons in a response card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, we cannot have more than the limit.
In slack you can have 5 buttons and in messenger you can have 3 buttons, max.
If you are giving more than the limit you won't get error but only first 3 (or 5) will be shown.

Comment: damn it. Can we add more response card in a single prompt?

Comment: yep. Max 10 i think. will get error if you define more. you can refer this answer for details https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646930/3196845

Comment: Can we prompt buttons in Amazon lex dynamically?

Comment: yes, have a look at the link i gave, buttons will come in the response card. that will solve all your problems. upvote both if it helps :D

Comment: without any response card, can we deploy buttons?

Comment: nope. but you can ignore image in the response card, s it will not take much space then.